5V relay to control amplifier
I am looking to use a MAJORITY Fitzwilliam 2024 DAB/Bluetooth radio in our kitchen which will be linked up to some passive ceiling and wall speakers. I am not keen on having to turn on and off an amplifier each time, although I may have to if this setup doesn't work.
I have looked into master/slave power extensions, but these seem sparsely available and reviews say they buzz, fail, and might not turn on/off correctly.
I am considering using a car amplifier's remote turn on wire to turn the amplifier on and off. (The amplifier will not be in view and volume can be controlled by the radio.) I would like to be sure how to connect the radio's 5V 1A power supply with a relay to the car amplifier.
Is it possible to connect a 5V relay to power a car amplifier? What would I need?

But the DAB radio 5V supply is providing 5V all the time regardless of if the DAB radio is active or in standby. So you can't use the 5V as a signal to turn on of off something, unless you unplug or switch the mains supply to 5V adapter, or, switch the 5V supply to radio. Which neither seems to be what you want to do. But it sure is possible to connect that always-on 5V to a relay and it will keep the car amp always on.
